# How does IIS7 decide when to invoke…?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, httpmodule

Q1) Assuming Http module is registered with IIS7 to be used for non-Asp.Net application ( say some Java app ) , when in the request’s life cycle will IIS7 invoke this module? Thus, how will IIS7 decide when to invoke it?

Q2)  In order to register Http module with IIS7, we need to put it in GAC. 
Is it possible to register Http module or Http handler without putting it in GAC?

thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A1.  Assuming you are using the integrated pipeline, the request life cycle is the same for .Net and non-.Net requests.  the "Failed Request Tracing Rules" feature of IIS7 will give you an extreme amount of detail about the events that fire during a request's lifecycle.  I've used that to debug HttpModules and it helps a lot.

A2.  Yes, you don't need to put an HttpModule in the GAC to register it.  As long as it is in your app's "bin" folder, IIS7 will be able to find it.

Comment: So in essence IIS 7 has its very own events, to which Http modules can be registered? But how do we register a custom Http module to a particular IIS 7 event?

Comment: IIS7's integrated pipline *is* the ASP.NET Pipeline that you know and love.  They have been merged.  They are not seperate events--they are the same events.

Comment: Now I’m confused. A) If the two pipelines are merged the way you say they are, then who does the actual firing of events … IIS7 or Asp.Net? B) Also, if the two are merged, are then only events fired (by this pipeline) the HttpApplication events ( BeginRequest, AuthenticateRequest, AuthorizeRequest ) or does this pipeline also have “its own, non-Asp.Net related” events? C) So IIS7’s native modules ( thus non-Asp.Net modules )are also subscribed/registered to HttpApplication events( BeginRequest, AuthenticateRequest etc )?

Comment: A. IIS7; B. I can't find anything that mentions non-Asp.net events; C. Yes